# LOOCV in Caret package ( randomForest example) - not unique results

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, caret

I pose you my doubts:
For what I know there is only a single way to perform a LOOCV for a model (i.e. testing each one of the N elements vs the model trained with the other N-1 elements).

Namely, this should be a LOOCV AUC:

```
library('randomForest')
library('pROC') #for ROC curve

irisData <- iris[1:60,]
irisData$Species <- as.factor(as.character(irisData$Species))

predictions <- 1:60

for (k in 1:60){ predictions[k] <- predict(randomForest(Species ~ Sepal.Length , data = irisData[-k,], mtry=1),type="prob", newdata = irisData[k,,drop=F])[2] }
auc(irisData$Species,predictions,direction="<", levels = levels(irisData$Species))
```

> Area under the curve: 0.776

Repeating the code i always obtain the same value.
By using caret, i obtain

```
library('caret')

fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = 'LOOCV',                # k-fold cross validation 'cv'
  number = 1,                     # number of folds
  savePredictions = 'final',       # saves predictions for optimal tuning parameter
  classProbs = T ,                 # should class probabilities be returned
  summaryFunction=twoClassSummary  # results summary function
) 

train(Species ~ Sepal.Length, data=irisData ,method='rf',   tuneGrid=data.frame(mtry=1)  ,trControl = fitControl)
```

With AUC values between 0.770 and 0.780.

I tried to change number to 60 but the result is the same.

Where is the issue?

Best.

Comment: Actually, the first code (the simple `randomForest`) does not give the same AUC-ROC value for me every time I run the code. And it should not be the same as by definition the RF algorithm is picking different random features to make the split. Only if we fixed the seed within the iteration we would get the same AUC-ROC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for randomForest you need to set the seed, you can see below:

```
library('randomForest')
library('pROC') 

irisData <- iris[1:60,]
irisData$Species <- as.factor(as.character(irisData$Species))

predictions <- 1:60

for (k in 1:60){
set.seed(1) 
predictions[k] <- predict(randomForest(Species ~ Sepal.Length , 
data = irisData[-k,], mtry=1),type="prob", 
newdata = irisData[k,,drop=F])[2] 
}
auc(irisData$Species,predictions,direction="<", 
levels = levels(irisData$Species))

Area under the curve: 0.776
```

For caret, you need a list of seed integers the length of your resampling, and the last one is the seed used for prediction on final model. So that makes a list of 61, all 1s, similar to above:

```
library('caret')

fitControl <- trainControl(
  method = 'LOOCV',                
  number = 1,                     
  savePredictions = 'final',        
  classProbs = T ,
  seed = as.list(rep(1,61)),                
  summaryFunction=twoClassSummary 
) 

train(Species ~ Sepal.Length, data=irisData ,method='rf',   
tuneGrid=data.frame(mtry=1)  ,trControl = fitControl)

60 samples
 1 predictor
 2 classes: 'setosa', 'versicolor' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Leave-One-Out Cross-Validation 
Summary of sample sizes: 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, 59, ... 
Resampling results:

  ROC    Sens  Spec
  0.776  1     0.6
```

Comment: Probably it was related to the missing seeds. Thank you

Comment: @GiulioBenetti, if you found this answer helpful, then please consider
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.